# How to turn off subsurf modifier on a lot of objects at the same time

Tags: modifiers

I have a model containing about 30 objects, all together about 900,000 vertices. My computer can't handle this amount of verticies and it gets realy slow. Is there a way how to turn on/off subsurf to all these objects at the same time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Simplify

Enable scene simplification in *Properties > Scene > Simplify* and set the subdivision level to 0:

[image]

## Copy to selected

1. Select all the objects
2. Disable the subsurf modifier in the viewport, then <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>*> Copy to selected*:

[image]